# Symfony : Dynamic add select box ( Add Dynamically select Language )

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, entity, symfony-forms

I'm searching how to implement a system of choosing languages dynamically using **form builder**.

[image: Form example]

so we must have two html array inputs field : name="languages[]" and the second will be name="languges_level[]"

So this system allows the user to set the language which he can speak with his level on it.

The User can add/remove Language dynamically before he submits the Form.

The Questions :

1- Form Level : what will be the field form type? I have to add 2 form fields which will be combined to create my result array which will be stored in the database. So this two field will be not mapped with ORM.

```
->add('langues', TYPEXXX:class) 
->add('langues_level', TYPEXXX:class)
```

3- Twig Level: should i make some change in the twig as well?

So what will be the best solution in my case?

My first try is :

```
->add('languages', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
    'entry_options'  => array(
        'choices'  => array(
                        'Français' => 'Français',
                        'English'     => 'English',
                        'Italien'    => 'Italien',
                        'Espanish'    => 'Espanish',
        ),
        'label'      => ' ',
    ),
))
->add('language_levels', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => ChoiceType::class,
    'entry_options'  => array(
        'choices'  => array(
                        'Beginner' => 'Beginner',
                        'Medium'     => 'Medium',
                        'Good'    => 'Good',
        ),
        'label'      => ' ',
    ),
));
```

but this don't work as I mentioned in the picture .. who had a perfect solution plz ?

Comment: Why don't you try my answer? I see you've edited your question and it looks a bit like my answers, but an essential part is different. You have created a list of languages and a list of levels, but you should combine them (what I called LanguageLevel)

Comment: @StephanVierkant : In LanguageLevel entity Class why did you define a user attribute ? is it nesessary ?

Comment: Yes, I think so? Please update your question with your entity model. I assumed you've got multiple users which can have multiple 'languagelevels' (Dutch - Good, English - Medium, German - Beginner).

Comment: Glad to see that my answer [helped you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439044/doctrine-manytoone-the-field-is-inserted-in-the-db-with-null-value). Don't forget to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a [Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).

> so we must have two html array inputs field : name="langues[]" and the
>   second will be name="langes_level[]"
>
> (..)
>
> 3- Twig Level: should i make some change in the twig as well?
>
> (..)
>
> 4- Javascript Level, i can develop it when the inputs are clean
>   created in the html.

No, no and no. Describing how your 'array input fields' should be named exactly is not the right mentality if you're using a framework like Symfony. Describe your entity fields, describe your form fields and Symfony will give all form elements a name. Symfony Forms will render and handle the form for you, so there is (very likely) no need to be bothered what the form element names are exactly.

Your entity class:

```
class LanguageLevel
{
    protected $user;
    protected $language;
    protected $level;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Create a form type:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('languages', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => LanguageLevelType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
        ));
    }
}
```

And a LanguageLevelType:

```
class LanguageLevelType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('language', LanguageType::class)
        ->add('level', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices'  => array(
                'Good' => 5,
                'Bad' => 1,
             ),
        ));
    }
}
```

If the rendered output is not what you want, check the documentation if you can configure the Form Types. Manually changing the twig template, your controller and/or javascripts for a specific case is possible, but I think the 'Collection of Forms' from above will cover your use case.