# Symfony 3.0+ : form CollectionType field doesn't generate any html input

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have to use a CollectionType field in my project and i excpect having a html input with name="langues[]" which will return an array but after copying the code from the Symfony official documentation, the field wasn't displayed in result. only the label is displayed.

Code I write :

```
    $builder->add('langues', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => TextType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'prototype' => true,
        'prototype_data' => 'New Tag Placeholder',
    ))
    ;
```

html generated that i take from the browser element inspector :

```
<div>
    <label class="required">Langues</label>
    <div id="homebundle_personnel_langues" data-prototype="<div><label for=&quot;homebundle_personnel_langues___name__&quot; class=&quot;required&quot;>__name__label__</label><input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;homebundle_personnel_langues___name__&quot; name=&quot;homebundle_personnel[langues][__name__]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; value=&quot;New Tag Placeholder&quot; /></div>">
    </div>
</div>
```

So, how to implment correctly a CollectionType ?

Comment: did you try this course? https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: a pitfall is that the parent entity must have one or more languages in the array before you will see them .

Comment: Frank B is right: by default your collection is empty, so there is nothing to show. By the way, consider looking at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367954/symfony-dynamic-add-select-box-add-dynamically-select-language) first, before asking similar questions. Other we will end up with many different question about the same issue: not understanding Collections.

Comment: The objectif of this website is to collect the maximum of questions that developpers can put on google research and honnestly i think that this question is independent from the other so there is many people who are going to use collection and maybe they ask such general question although the other question is very particular.

thanks for your supports.

Comment: No, the goal of this site is **not** to collect as much questions as possible. The goal is to generate **well-written, practical, detailed questions and answers**. It's not the amount of questions that makes this site great, it's the quality of them. You've got **four** questions about one problem: not understanding how collection work. Please read the documentation and look for similar questions (starting with your own!) first. And please reply to your [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367954/symfony-dynamic-add-select-box-add-dynamically-select-language).

Comment: I downvoted your question because it doesn't show enough research effort. Reading the documentation would have solved the problem. And your answer shows you didn't read it (carefully) after @FrankB's comment.

Answer (score 0):

So the response for this question is that we must initialise the attribute **$langues** which is defined as an array in the entity, to have at least one collection field.

```
// entity class :
private $langues = array('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you follow the [documentation's example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)?

```
class Task
{
    protected $description;

    protected $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $task = new Task();

        // dummy code - this is here just so that the Task has some tags
        // otherwise, this isn't an interesting example
        $tag1 = new Tag();
        $tag1->setName('tag1');
        $task->getTags()->add($tag1);
        $tag2 = new Tag();
        $tag2->setName('tag2');
        $task->getTags()->add($tag2);
        // end dummy code

        //etc.
    }
}
```

So in your case

```
class Personnel
{    
    protected $langues;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->langues = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```