# doctrine : ManyToOne : the field is inserted in the DB with NULL value

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have made a relation OneToMany between two fields **personnelLanguages(class Personnel)** and **personnel(class LanguagesPersonnel)** and the problem is that in the insert I have the field personnel_id = NULL in the table personnel_languages:

```
   id   personnel_id    level   language
    7   NULL                5         5
    8   NULL                5         1
```

**Entities** :

Personnel Entity :

```
/**
 * Personnel
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="personnel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="HomeBundle\Repository\PersonnelRepository")
 */
class Personnel
{
    // some fields 
    /**
      * @var collection
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonnelLanguages" , mappedBy="personnel" , cascade={"all"})
      */
    private $personnelLanguages;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->personnelLanguages = new ArrayCollection(array(new PersonnelLanguages(),new PersonnelLanguages()) );
    }
    // getters and setters


    /**
     * @return collection
     */
    public function getPersonnelLanguages()
    {
        return $this->personnelLanguages;
    }

    /**
     * @param collection $personnelLanguages
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public function setPersonnelLanguages(collection $personnelLanguages)
    {
        $this->personnelLanguages = $personnelLanguages;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

PersonnelLanguages Entity :

```
/**
 * PersonnelLanguages
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="personnel_languages")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="HomeBundle\Repository\PersonnelLanguagesRepository")
 */
 class PersonnelLanguages{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var int
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Personnel", inversedBy="personnelLanguages")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personnel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $personnel;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $language;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $level;
    // getters and setters
}
```

** FORMS ** :

PersonnelType :

```
->add("personnelLanguages",CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => PersonnelLanguagesType::class,
            'entry_options' => array("label"=>false),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ))
```

So when i create a new Personnel which includes a personnelLanguages field, i have a NULL value for personnel_id in the table personnel_languages.

A Thought : may be beacause in the moment of the creation the personnel_id doesn't exist !!!

**Debug** :

I have debugged the action and I discover with those two **print_r** that the **id** in the personnel object doesn't exist until the **die**

Should doctrine manage this problem automatically or I have a problem in my code ?

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $personnel = new Personnel();
        $form = $this->createForm('HomeBundle\Form\PersonnelType', $personnel);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            print_r($personnel->getId()); echo "--";
            print_r($personnel->getpersonnelLanguages()); die;

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($personnel);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('personnel_show', array('id' => $personnel->getId()));
        }
```

Comment: Hint:  ask yourself where does PersonnelLanguage::setPersonnel() get called?

Comment: I mentioned in the code that the getters and setters are already declared.

Comment: Declaring does not mean they are being called.  This is actually one of the most common Doctrine questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: I had added in my question getter and setter of the collection field personnelLanguages of the entity Personnel  and the getter and the setter of personnel of entity personnelLanguages is also OK. so what's the matter in your opinion ?

Comment: Doctrine will take care of setting personnel_id when the entity is saved.  What Doctrine will not do is call PersonnelLanguage::setPersonnel().  And off topic but the [dump](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) function provides more info than print_r.

Comment: And yes I could just go ahead and give the simple fix for this particular issue.  Save you the trouble of looking for previous identical questions.  But you have other problems as well.  I'd suggest installing a fresh project and then work through the steps in the docs: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html You will see what I mean.